# How can I increase the size of the clipboard in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, clipboard, copy-paste

How can I  increase the size of the clipboard in Windows 7?

While copying large amounts of data, I get the following error:

> Item to large for Clipboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to increase the size of the Clipboard:

1. Click the `Start` button. Type `sysdm.cpl` into the search box and
   press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
2. Click the `Advanced` tab in the `System Properties` window.
   Click the `Settings` button under the `Performance` label header.
3. Click the `Advanced` tab in the `Performance Options` window. Under
   the `Virtual Memory` header, click the `Change...` button.
4. Clear the check box next to the `Automatically manage paging file
   size for all drives` option. This disables automatic "Virtual
   Memory" settings in Windows.
5. Enter a value for the size of the new paging file. Enter a value
   larger than the current paging file size in the "Maximum Size" field
   (enter the value in megabytes). Click the `Set` button and then
   `OK`.
6. Restart the computer for the new "Virtual Memory" settings to take
   effect. The Windows Clipboard now stores more data when copying and
   pasting between applications.

Reference: [I need to increase the clip board size in Word](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/i-need-to-increase-the-clip-board-size-in-word/99adc8c1-8f4b-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?msgId=7ac373a1-144c-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5)

A detailed blog with screenshots :http://sforsuresh.in/increase-size-clipboard-of-windows-10-7/

Answer (score 4):

Even after setting the Swapfile (Virtual Memory) to 65GB, I can still not copy and paste more than 65000 lines from Access to the Clipboard.

However, I can copy and paste more than 65000 lines in Excel easily. So the issue lies with Access not being able to copy enough rows to the Clipboard.

I have been searching for the solution since 2013. The problem seems with Access not being able to transfer more than 65000 rows to the Clipboard.

The only way presently is to create a query, then right-click on it and export to Excel.

Once the data is in another format, you can select all rows, and copy and paste from there.